# Read long hex data from serial port with php-dio

Tags: php, serial-port

I use PHP-DIO extension for communicate with a fingerprint reader. The device creates a finger image and sends it back through RS232 serial port. It's quite long, 64520 bytes of pure data, not a string.

My problem is, I get sometimes not all bytes, just 50-60000. 
With GTKTerm in Linux, or RealTerm in Windows works well and my shorter commands (identification with fingerprint, user registration, etc...) work well too.

Why stops sometimes data reading by 50-60k bytes and why just sometimes?

My serial driver code:

```
protected function openPort(){
    try 
    {
        $c = stream_context_create(array('dio' => 
                    array('data_rate' => $this->baudRate,
                          'data_bits' => $this->bits, 
                          'stop_bits' => $this->spotBit, 
                          'parity' => 0, 
                          'is_canonical' => 0,
                        )));
        $bbSerialPort = null;
        if (strtoupper(substr(PHP_OS, 0, 3)) === 'LIN'){  
                $bbSerialPort = fopen('dio.raw:///dev/ttyUSB0', 'r+', false, $c);
                exec('stty -F /dev/ttyUSB0 115200 line 0 min 60 time 0 ignbrk -brkint -icrnl -imaxbel -opost -onlcr -isig -icanon -iexten -echo -echoe -echok -echoctl -echoke eof undef flush undef start undef stop undef');
        }
        if(!$bbSerialPort){
            var_dump("Could not open Serial port {$this->portName} ");
            exit;
        }
        $this->serialResource = $bbSerialPort;
        return 1;
    } 
    catch (Exception $e){
            exit($e->getMessage());
    } 
}


public function sendCommand($command){
fwrite($this->serialResource, call_user_func_array('pack',$command) );

stream_set_blocking($this->serialResource, 0);

$runForSeconds = new DateInterval("PT3S");
$endTime = (new DateTime())->add($runForSeconds);
$answer = "";
while (new DateTime() < $endTime) {
        $data = fread($this->serialResource,1);
        if ($data !== "") {
            $tmp = unpack('H*', $data);
            $answer .= $tmp[1];
            $endTime = (new DateTime())->add($runForSeconds);
        }
}
    return $answer;
}
```

Comment: You have `exec('stty ... min 60 time 0 ...` and `$data = fread(...,1);`  This looks like you're asking for *"undefined behavior"* according to [Understanding UNIX termios VMIN and VTIME](http://www.unixwiz.net/techtips/termios-vmin-vtime.html)

Comment: Thanks for your tip, I have tried all 4 variations with VTIME and VMIN, with fread(..., <VTIME, 128, 512,.....> values, but I get always the same result. 2-3 times out of 10 I get less bytes.

Comment: Claiming that you *"tried all 4 variations"* is like describing your code instead of showing it.  Besides, there's really only one practical combination to use.

Comment: Seems like you are insisting on very high system overhead and inefficiency by using `fread(...,1)`. What are you using for flow control on this serial connection to prevent receive buffer overrun, i.e. is there hardware handshake aka RTS/CTS?

Comment: All 4 variations means:
exec('stty -F /dev/ttyUSB0 115200 line 0 min 0 time 0  ...other stuff');

exec('stty -F /dev/ttyUSB0 115200 line 0 min 60 time 10 ...other stuff');

exec('stty -F /dev/ttyUSB0 115200 line 0 min 60 time 0 ...other stuff');

exec('stty -F /dev/ttyUSB0 115200 line 0 min 0 time 10 ...other stuff');

I use now fread(..., 512) or stream_get_contents($resource);

I don't have hardware handshake or RTS/CTS. Is it a problem?